# my code storage data in local storage on a website but when i navigate through the pages and register a new user the old user are deleted

Tags: javascript, html, push

```
       var userInfo = [];

          var myCostum;

            //documentgetElementById("registerForm");

               document.getElementById("registerForm").addEventListener("click", function () 
                   {

               //var register = document.querySelector('#registerForm');

                 var name = document.querySelector('#fN').value;
                 var lastN = document.querySelector('#lN').value;
                 var userName = document.querySelector('#uN').value;    
                 var passwrd = document.querySelector('#pS').value; 



                  userInfo.push([name,lastN,userName,passwrd]);

              localStorage.setItem("myCostum", JSON.stringify(userInfo));


                  });
```

I am using separate files for j, my website has a navigation bar with home,register,login,about me and shopping car. this code works fine if i register more than one user, i can see the users in the local storage on all pages and i can even sign in. the problem is when i go to register again and register a new user the users that i reister before are deleted and replaced by the new user. also if i go to home page i can an error (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at even-listener.js:9). i just do not had idea why register page seems to work but the rest not. I had another code using onclick in html but the same it does not give any error in any page but the users gone when i register new one after navigating through my pages. this is the first time using localStorage and i do not can i do or if it is normal. i am stack and i need to keep adding more code but i want to solve this problem first.

Comment: I think it's because you're just saving the userInfo to local storage which replaces the previous value. Get the previous value first from local storage, append to it and save again.

Comment: Because you're declaring ```userInfo``` as an empty array. Of course, each time the page refreshes, it's an empty array again. And when you push an item to it, it will contain only one item. You save it to local  storage and it replaces the previous value.

Comment: Why are you registering users in `localStorage` (which is on client device) instead of on the server?

Comment: because I have to use only javascript, .html, jquery and css. I not learning database yet. It most look has real or close to real website but it is not real. I hope you understand

Answer (score 0):

Lots of things going on here, but let me start from the basics.

1st never use local storage for sensitive information such as usernames and passwords. There's a lot of sites that copy local storages and send it to malicious people.

2nd you could in theory use session storage limited to the tab, but you still could be under the danger of xss.

3rd when the browser closes, all your data will be lost from the local storage anyway

As for your code.  Your user info,  should not be initiated as empty.  You must get the previous value from local storage and push to it. Otherwise you are just overriding the previous value.

```
var userInfo = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myCustom'));
```

Comment: i won't use this website, it's just for practice. I will try what you suggested.